# How to make Pydantic discriminate a nested object based on a field?

Tags: python, pydantic, discriminated-union

I have this Pydantic model:

```py
import typing
import pydantic

class TypeAData(pydantic.BaseModel):
    aStr: str

class TypeBData(pydantic.BaseModel):
    bNumber: int

class TypeCData(pydantic.BaseModel):
    cBoolean: bool

class MyData(pydantic.BaseModel):
    type: typing.Literal['A', 'B', 'C']
    name: str
    data: TypeAData | TypeBData | TypeCData
```

However, if `type` is equal to "A" and `data` contains `TypeBData`, it'll validate correctly when it shouldn't. This could be an alternative:

```py
class MyData(pydantic.BaseModel):
    type: typing.Literal['A', 'B', 'C']
    name: str
    data: TypeAData | TypeBData | TypeCData

    @pydantic.validator('data', pre=True, always=True)
    def validate_data(cls, data):
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            data_type = data.get('type')
            if data_type == 'A':
                return TypeAData(**data)
            elif data_type == 'B':
                return TypeBData(**data)
            elif data_type == 'C':
                return TypeCData(**data)

        raise ValueError('Invalid data or type')
```

It works; however, is there a better way to do it without repeating the enum keys (`'A'`, `'B'` and `'C'`) and values (`TypeAData`, `TypeBData` and `TypeCData`) twice?

I've tried using [discriminated unions](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/types/unions/#discriminated-unions-aka-tagged-unions), but since the `type` field and the discriminated fields are in different levels within the model (the latter is inside a nested object), I could not make further progress on this.

Comment: Hard to understand what are you trying to achieve... Does it mean, that field "data" in class MyData is dependant on field "type"? Imho, such fields should go together in separate models

Comment: Yes, I think I made that clear in the second code snippet. Also I don't control the schema, I'm reading it from an API. Is there a solution?

Comment: enzo, but you control models, don't you? So you can redesign your models above.